# How to set up several alerts for different lists

Tags: 2013, alert, sharepoint-calendar, sharepoint-email

I've got an alerts set up for a deployment calendar that i am implementing into Sharepoint Calendar function - Currently it's all fine with the overlays and categories and the colours match up with no issues and they send e-mails when a new appointment is added.

The only issue is that the e-mails go for every category set up. I have 3 categories set up - QA, Pre Prod and Prod. At the minute I receive an e-mail for each alert set up regardless of the category - I only need alerts for Pre-Prod and Prod

So my question is - How can I disable the alert for the QA Category??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have been able to do this via Sharepoint designer

```
Stage:eMailAlert
If Current Item:Environment equals Production
or Current Item:Environment equals Production
or Current Item:Environment equals Production
or Current Item:Environment equals Production
or Current Item:Environment equals PRODUCTION
    Email Alex 
Else
    If Current Item:Environment equals XXXX
    or Current Item:Environment equals XXXX
    or Current Item:Environment equals XXXX 
    or Current Item:Environment equals XXXX
    or Current Item:Environment equals XXXX
        Email Alex 
Transition to stage
Go to End of Workflow
```

This now send's e-mails when the event is added to the calendar